# Cannot call methods of service from MainActivity

Tags: android, service

I have a service that has various methods and all they do is give a logcat message but these methods doesn't seem to be called even though I have created a instance of that service in my activity class.
My service class code is-

```
public class service extends Service {
IBinder ob=new My_Ibinder();


public class My_Ibinder extends Binder{
    public service get_MyService(){
        return service.this;
    }

  }


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
Log.e("SERVICE CREATED","");

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e("SERVICE OnStartCommand","");
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.e("SERVICE onBind","");
        return ob;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("SERVICE DESTROYED","");
    }

    String data(){
        Log.e("SERVICE data method","");

        return "DATA SUCCESSFULLY TRANSFERRED";
    }

    public void ok(){
        Log.e("SERVICE ok method","");
    }


}
```

Here the methods I call are data() and ok().
My activity class is-

```
Button start,stop,data,check;
    TextView tv;
    service ser;
    Boolean flag=false;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
        check=(Button)findViewById(R.id.check);
        stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
        data=(Button)findViewById(R.id.data);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){public void onClick(View v){ bindService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,service.class),sc,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);  }});
        stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){public void onClick(View v){    unbindService(sc);  flag=false;    }});
        data.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){public void onClick(View v){    ser.ok();tv.setText(ser.data());      }});
        check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){public void onClick(View v){     Log.e(""+flag,"sfsfsdfdssfsdffsdfs");     }});

    }


    private ServiceConnection sc=new ServiceConnection(){

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            My_Ibinder ob=(My_Ibinder)service;
            ser=ob.get_MyService();
            flag=true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            flag=false;
            ser=null;
        }

    };
```

On clicking the button I don't get any logcat message. Neither from the methods I need to call, nor from the onCreate(),onBind() and onDestroy() methods which should have been called if the service is successfully created.
I've checked running processes in settings and this service doesn't exist over there.
Strangely, if I start the service with startService(intent) then it seems to work fine(although I'm not able to communicate with it). I guess there is some problem with Binding the service.
Kindly Help.

Comment: Did you put the service in your manifest?

Comment: yes I've already added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it... Such a silly silly mistake I've done. While giving logcat message I didn't added a text attribute to it and it just had a tag. Now that I've added a text to it, it works perfectly. Such a small yet important point to be noted. Certainly we all use logcat messages to DEBUG our program but this time the PROBLEM was LOGCAT itself. Never gonna forget this one !!!

Answer (score 0):

Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html to communicate service from activity.

Comment: But the documentation says that you can use either of the methods( binder or aidl) to communicate with the activity. I find binder less complex. Can you please tell me where I'm wrong in the code.